# How to hash the contents of a file in C?

Tags: c, hash, md5, sha

What is the proper way to hash the contents of a file in C? I'm not trying to hash the file as a whole but rather line by line for the file. My main goal is to create a program that searches for hash collisions. I've written the program in C but it uses the system command to hash each line with both MD5 and SHA256. I understand that using the system command is unsafe and not the proper way to do this so I'm reaching out to the community to get the proper way to hash with MD5 and SHA256.

Comment: There are a number of *"String Hash Functions"* available, a quick search will disclose many, including `md5` and `sha256`. Two good general hash table links are [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx). Essentially you want to read/hash each line. (a good test for collisions is the `/usr/share/dict/words` file which will provide between 100,000 and 300,000 words (one per-line)

Comment: As a general, "new user" note -- Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Making sure your question is on-topic will help others provide a concise rather than general answer (and prevent downvotes as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use OpenSSL C APIs

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    unsigned char sha256_digest[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char md5_digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char *buffer = "Hello World!";
    int i;

    SHA256(buffer, strlen(buffer), sha256_digest);
    MD5(buffer, strlen(buffer), md5_digest);


    for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%02x", sha256_digest[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%02x", md5_digest[i]);
    }

}
```

To compile this code you need to link it properly using the `crypto` library

```
 gcc testmd5.c -lcrypto
```

Once you execute, you will get this output

```
 7f83b1657ff1fc53b92dc18148a1d65dfc2d4b1fa3d677284addd200126d9069
 ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c
```

Comment: fixed the code, thanks for the review, also fixed the output